# I want to update a file with rollno. and name from a csv file where name and roll no are separated by comma

Tags: postgresql, unix, echo

My input file is a csv file containing details as:

```
2233,anish sharma
2234,azad khan
2235,birbal singh
2236,chaitanya kumar
```

my expected output is display of the two details in two separate columns.

I executed following code. Full name is not getting displayed. The part after space doesn't appear. What changes should be done?

```
echo "Roll no updation"
tput cup 10 10
echo "Key in file name (rollno,name separated by comma)"
tput cup 12 10
read infile
for i in `cat $infile`
do
    rollno=`echo $i|cut -d , -f1`
    name=`echo $i|cut -d , -f2`
    psql -U postgres -A -t -F, -c "update student set name = '$name' where rollno = '$rollno' current record" >bq 
done
```

Comment: Can you please paste both files in proper text format? Also paste sample input and expected output.

Comment: sample input: 3356,anish sharma

Comment: @KunalGurbani Can you place a `echo $name` in your script after the command `name=echo $i|cut -d , -f2`. Check whether full name appears here or not. If it does, then the issue is with your `psql` command.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to import the text file into a temporary table (using `copy` or `\copy`) and then run a single `UPDATE` statement that joins the temp table with the target table (or it might even use `INSERT ON CONFLICT` to do an insert of new rows and an update of existing ones

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be written in this fashion

```
# comma separates records
IFS=,
cat "$infile" | while read rollno name; do
    psql -U postgres -A -t -F, -c \
        "update student set name = '$name'
         where rollno = '$rollno'" >bq
done
```

But you should be aware that this code is susceptible to SQL injection. Only use it if you can trust the source of the data!

Any `'` in the file will cause errors and worse.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this executed some lines, but not all. I think there's some other problem.